# How big Minecraft by each block on xbox

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

How big is minecraft block? Minecraft is the earth in a cube and each side if the cube there 4 worlds. You can have more than 4 worlds but each side of the cube is 4 worlds so how many blocks is there in Minecraft?

Comment: Each block is 1 meter cubed.

Answer (score 3):

In Minecraft, the world is actually a plane, not a cube. There's only one side of the world. It's not like a cube-shaped version of earth. In the PC version, the world expands infinitely, however, in the console version, worlds are limited to 864x864 blocks, giving a world a total area of 746,496 square blocks.

Minecraft has 3 other realms (I'm avoiding the use of the word "dimension" in order to not confuse the issue) however; the Nether and the End. The End is 864x864 blocks, but the Nether is 288x288.